# How can I make a variable change-able in the console

Tags: javascript

I want to make a variable change-able in the console for example

```
  var numbers = 5;
  var mynumbers = 3;
  var outcome = numbers - mynumbers;

  console.log(outcome);
```

I want to be able to change var `numbers` and `mynumbers` in the console and var `outcome` to get printed after

Comment: If they are global, you can just change them.  But that will not make the console.log re-run.  Javascript is, for the most part, procedural logic.  It's not going to reprocess logic unless you write it to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Numbers are immutable. If you change `numbers` or `mynumbers` it won't change the value of `outcome` because that has already been determined. Likewise, if you change `outcome` then that has already been logged and the log won't change.

If you made the value of `outcome` an object and then mutated it (by changing a property on it) then that **might** be reflected in the log (as some logging systems are lazy about evaluating objects).

Answer (score 0):

```
let outcome = 0;
numbers = {
  innerValue: 10,
  innerListener: function(val) {},
  set value(val) {
    this.innerValue = val;
    this.innerListener(val);
  },
  get value() {
    return this.innerValue;
  },
  registerListener: function(listener) {
    this.innerListener = listener;
  }
}

myNumbers = {
  innerValue: 10,
  innerListener: function(val) {},
  set value(val) {
    this.innerValue = val;
    this.innerListener(val);
  },
  get value() {
    return this.innerValue;
  },
  registerListener: function(listener) {
    this.innerListener = listener;
  }
}

numbers.registerListener((val)=> {
 outcome=val-myNumbers.innerValue; 
})
myNumbers.registerListener((val)=> {
 outcome=numbers.innerValue-val; 
})

numbers.value = 10;
myNumbers.value= 5;
//voila => outcome is now  5.
```